# Migration from internal network TFS to VSTS

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops, devops

We have an internal server in a company for TFS which is contained in more than 100 projects. We are walking on the edge! Therefore the company made a decision to move all the projects to Visual studio team services (VSTS). Unfortunately, It cost so much time if we are gonna move the projects one by one.

I also tried Git-TF or Git-TFS but it was not successful and so frustrating. I got some errors every time and then I gave up.

Is there any way to move all the projects to VSTS at once or at least import them by VSTS? (For example, i import the Github projects directly from VSTS. But now instead of Github we have a computer as a server inside the company)

I appreciate that any suggestion or help.

Comment: Are all projects in TFS under Git version control?  What error did you get when you use  Git-TF or Git-TFS?

Comment: Are you able to migrate git repos using the steps I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a high fidelity database migration, you should check @DenverDev's reply, he has provided correct links there.

If you only want to migrate a complete Git Repository from TFS to VSTS, you could try the steps in [this blog](https://roadtoalm.com/2017/02/10/migrate-a-complete-git-repository-from-tfs-to-vsts/):

1. Clone the Git repo with everything in it: `git clone  [tfs git url] --mirror`
2. Add the new remote: `git remote add vsts [vsts git url]`
3. Push all the changes: `git push vsts --mirror`

Comment: I was not able to pull the projects just with git command line. Therefore I used git-tfs and I pulled down all the projects. Is there any way to push them all at the same time or I have to do number 2-3 manually?

Comment: You could try `git push vsts --mirror --all`.

Comment: The problem with Git-TFS is it pulled all the projects and it made just one git folder for all the projects. It means I have one git URL which is contained of all the projects ( almost 100 projects ). But is it possible when I used git-tfs and pull the project from tfs, it makes git for each project separately? or if I can make them with seperated git repo on VSTS ?

Comment: I guess the reason that I have one repo for all the project is, I have chosen the root, Otherwise, i needed to do the same for more than 100 projects.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't make your projects with separated git repo on VSTS at the same time. You have to add new remote one by one.

Comment: Finally, I pulled everything down on my local machine and with c# and VSTS API, I created the repositories based on project's folder name and then moved all projects to their own repositories. Thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comprehensive script for automating the clone of all your git repos to your Azure DevOps project using powershell, and the TFS api.  I'm going from TFS 2018:

```
# get all repositories
$TfsUrl = "http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myProject/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1"
$repos = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TfsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials

# set the auth header from a PAT
$myPAT = "aaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccdddddddd111111123"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("aaduser@domain.com:$myPAT")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")}

# get Azure DevOps project id
$adoPURL = "https://dev.azure.com/myOrganization/_apis/projects?api-version=4.1"
$adoProjectId = ((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $adoPURL -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers).value | where {$_.name -eq "myADOProject"}).id

# loop through each TFS repository, clone it, and push it to your Azure DevOps project
foreach ($repo in $repos.value) {
    Write-Host "cloning $($repo.name)"

    # set to the root folder, and mirror clone the repo
    Set-Location C:\clone_repo
    git clone --mirror http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myProject/_git/$($repo.name)

    # create the new remote git repo in your Azure DevOps project
    $json = '{"name":"' + $($repo.name) + '","project":{"id":"' + $adoProjectId + '"}}'
    $vUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/myOrganization/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$vUrl" -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Headers $headers

    # push the morrored repo to the remote
    Set-Location "$($repo.name).git"
    git remote set-url --push origin https://dev.azure.com/myOrganization/myADOProject/_git/$($repo.name)
    git push --mirror
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a fairly comprehensive guide for migrating from TFS to VSTS.

[Migration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migrate-to-vsts-from-tfs)

[Migrate to Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/?utm_source=ms&utm_medium=guide&utm_campaign=vstsdataimportguide)

If you have already tried this and are having specific errors, please post additional information.